# How to Print Data from MS Access Using VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, printing

I need to print data from the MS Access using VB from Visual Studio Community Edition. Can you help me with this problem? I am a newbie on VB by the way.

Comment: Look into [`PrintDocument`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi386bq1drJAhUxpoMKHTW2AE0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.drawing.printing.printdocument(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFdKwqCNJY7gUkQDLRLRDb6GxDBIg&sig2=M7ItNfJxCvrhgXl7qnN8LQ&bvm=bv.109910813,d.amc).

Comment: @OneFineDay It looks like making a PDF File. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right.  A `PrintDocument` allows you to use GDI+ to draw on a canvas and then what you draw gets sent to the printer and ends up on a piece of paper.

Comment: Thought it is like same with the Zend PDF on PHP @jmcilhinney

Comment: I have np idea what Zend PDF is but the `PrintDocument` class is nothing to do with PDFs specifically.  The only reason it would have anything to do with PDFs is if you chose a PDF writer as the printer.

Comment: @jmcilhinney cause I can see that it is using x and y co-ordinate to plot the data on the paper same as making PDF on PHP. Don't worry about it... it is just my observation. Thanks for the Reply.